# Is there anyway to force is_singular() to be true when not loading template?

Tags: functions

I need to export post content with all filters applied to a custom API that displays in JSON.

Everything is working up until I get to one plugin: Amazon AI.

The Amazon AI plugin exports the audio player when the current page `is_singular()` returns true. However, I am not loading templates in the API exporter.

Is there a way to force is_singular() to be true outside of a template, or possibly load some sort of empty template with the needed variables?

This is what I am calling from the API that fails in the Amazon AI `is_singular()` if statement:

```
global $post;
$post = get_post($post_id);
$content = apply_filters('the_content',$post->post_content);
```

It doesn't seem necessary to include the amazon ai plugin code but for reference here is the file causing the trouble: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-for-wordpress/blob/master/public/class-amazonpolly-public.php

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand, nevertheless:

Maybe you could instead try to trace back when the specific action from amazon plugin is registered. (lets call this hook_registration)

And also the hook when your problem occurs, lets call this ( hook_execution )

So, just hook yourself anywhere between hook_activation and hook_execution, and, inside the function, you can use remove_action to delete the problematic action, ( potentially with some if statements if needed)

EDIT: same logic applies for filters instead of actions.